# Implement Derived Class as Base on Constructor Exception?

Tags: c#, casting

I'm working with code to implement a hardware test system, which involves communication with several benchtop instruments. When I instantiate an instance of one of these instruments, the constructor attempts to open the communication session with the instrument. If that fails, I can throw all kinds of errors, but what I'd like to do is to have the instrument object default to a virtual or simulation mode where no actual communication is done but I can still run my code.

Right now I have all instruments of one type inheriting from a base class. I've added virtual methods to the base class which perform these debugging functions, but I'm stuck on a clean way to modify the derived object at creation time to implement the base classes methods when the communication session fails.

The ideal solution would be to have the constructor (technically the new keyword) return an instance of the base class instead of the derived class, but I've done a fair amount of searching and that doesn't appear to be possible.

I could add a property to the derived class to use as a boolean flag where every method in the derived class tests against that flag and invokes the base class method if true, but I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution that doesn't require a few hundred if statements and a serious flogging of base.Stuff() calls.

I have a few dozen methods and a handful of instruments inheriting in this way so a solution that doesn't require an explicit change to every one of those overriding methods would go a long, long way.

```
public abstract class BaseInstrument
{
    public string Address;
    protected MessageBasedSession MbSession;

    public virtual string Identify()
    {
        return "Debugging mode, fake identity";
    }
}


public class SpecificInstrument : BaseInstrument
{
    public SpecificInstrument(string address)
    {
        Address = address;
        try
        {
            MbSession = (MessageBasedSession)ResourceManager.GetLocalManager().Open(Address);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Return an object modified in such a way that it invokes base class virtual methods
            // instead of method overrides.
            // Constructor has no return value (that comes from the new keyword) so I can't
            // just return an instance of the base class...
        }
    }

    public override string Identify()
    {
        return ActualInstrumentRead();
    }

    // ...
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SpecificInstrument instr = new SpecificInstrument(ipAddress);
        Console.WriteLine(instr.Identify()); // Would like to print the debug case if eg. my LAN is down
    }
}
```

I feel like I might be missing an obvious solution to this but I've been scratching my head for hours.

Comment: what about if you reference base keyword intead of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a `BaseInstrument` from a `SpecificInstrument` constructor.

One alternative would be to put this logic where you create this instrument:

```
BaseInstrument instrument;
try {
    instrument = new SpecificInstrument();
}
catch {
    instrument = new BaseInstrument();
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the simple answer I figured I was missing, thanks! In the end I ended up abstracting this check with a general factory class which produces instances of the correct type given the situation, but this is the most basic form of the right answer, I believe.